# Get the position and length of a word in a line

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to divide a line by word and then give for each the length and the position in the line.

```
for word in $line 
do 
    start=`awk -v a="$Logline" -v b="$word" 'BEGIN{print index(a,b)}'` 
    count=`echo $word|wc -m` 
    echo $word : $start : $count
done
```

So let's suppose:

> line = 'This is a test to test'

I would Obtain :

> This : 0 : 4
>
> is   : 5 : 2
>
> a    : 8 : 1
>
> test : 10 : 4
>
> to   : 15 : 2
>
> test : 18 : 4

With this solution, the problem appears when two words are identical. Someone has an idea of how to do this?

Comment: Post, say, 10 lines of sample input (including any hard-to-handle cases you can think of) and expected output as it's not clear what you're trying to do and what your definition of a "word" is. Is `$line` truly a different variable from `$Logline` or is that a typo?

Comment: Yes sorry I have edited my post to add more informations.

Comment: I asked for 10 lines containing hard-to-handle cases and you posted 1 line of the trivial case where it's space-separated alphabetic characters. Come on, put a LITTLE effort into thinking about this or you're going to get a solution that will fall apart at the first non-trivial line (e.g. if a line that contains `here's` instead of `here is` - is `here's` a word or are `here` and `s` separate words or ....?).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I'll always have trivial case as my example. All the file I need to parse follow the same architecture which is really simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one space between words, you could do:

```
$>echo "this test is a test" | sed 's/ / \n/g'| awk 'BEGIN{i=0}{print $1, ":", i, length($1);i+=length($0)}'
this : 0 4
test : 5 4
is : 10 2
a : 13 1
test : 15 4
```

Comment: That's what i need thank you :) I have just a problem with your solution, i get this result : this : 0 4. The script stop after the first word.

Comment: I just past your solution in my terminal. I'm on a Mac {Maverick}, i don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: When i send that in my terminal : 

 $>echo "this test is a test" | sed 's/ / \n/g' ;

The Output  :

$>this ntest nis na ntest. That's weird ?

Comment: No, that is not weird at all because only some seds will interpret `\n` as a newline. The portable way to get a newline in sed is a backslash followed by a literal newline.

Comment: Thank you :). I replaced sed 's/ / \n/g' By sed -e 's/ /\'$'\n/g' and it works

Comment: Just use a backslash then a newline - what you wrote is just luckily being interpreted as you want by the shell but it doesn't actually make sense syntactically. You never need sed+awk, the whole thing can be written as `echo "this test is a test" | awk -v RS='[[:space:]]' '{print $0, i+0, length; i+=(length+1)}'` (used GNU awk for multi-char RS).

Comment: Thank you for this advice :) That works perfectly with awk. I'll will try to learn a bit more about this tool which seems to be really powerfull !

Answer (score 2):

**May be** you are trying to do this:

```
$ cat file
Hi my name is jaypal
i am a software software test engineer
scripting in awk awk awk is my hobby
```

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "Line=%d Length=%d Word=%s\n",NR,length($i),$i}' file
Line=1 Length=2 Word=Hi
Line=1 Length=2 Word=my
Line=1 Length=4 Word=name
Line=1 Length=2 Word=is
Line=1 Length=6 Word=jaypal
Line=2 Length=1 Word=i
Line=2 Length=2 Word=am
Line=2 Length=1 Word=a
Line=2 Length=8 Word=software
Line=2 Length=8 Word=software
Line=2 Length=4 Word=test
Line=2 Length=8 Word=engineer
Line=3 Length=9 Word=scripting
Line=3 Length=2 Word=in
Line=3 Length=3 Word=awk
Line=3 Length=3 Word=awk
Line=3 Length=3 Word=awk
Line=3 Length=2 Word=is
Line=3 Length=2 Word=my
Line=3 Length=5 Word=hobby
```

Comment: In fact, I would like to have the position in the line. I edited my post to explain what i want to have in the end. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
This is a test to test
$
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ OFS=" : " }
{
    start = 0
    while ( match($0,/[^ ]+/) ) {
        start = start + RSTART - 1
        print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH), start, RLENGTH
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        start = start + RLENGTH
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
This : 0 : 4
is : 5 : 2
a : 8 : 1
test : 10 : 4
to : 15 : 2
test : 18 : 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pos=0
for word in $line
do
    length=`expr length "$word"`
    echo "$word : $pos : $length"
    pos=`expr $pos + 1`
done
```